# When is EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD created on the stack?

Tags: seh

I want to understand when `EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD`s get created on the stack.

- Are they created when the program starts?
- Are they created when we enter the function?
- Or are they created only when the exception occurs?

Is it true that there is one `EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD` per `try`/`catch`?

Comment: Could you please clarify one thing. You tagged it as [tag:seh], but you mention `try`/`catch`. Now in MSVC C++ exceptions are implemented in terms of SEH, but are you solely interested in the C++ side of things or in general?

Comment: I mean a MSVC C++ try/catch. I am interested in the wide general thing

Comment: I replaced my original answer because I was somehow describing the exception_record rather than the exception_registration_record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD is placed on the stack in anticipation of an exception occurring.  The "try" will put one there.  The record is part of a chain, for as many nested "try" statements as exist.  The nesting includes one function calling another function from within a try block.  Windows will also put a top-most handler there before the program starts, so there is always one on program start.